# Huawei gallery rejects app because its a test app but its not

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

recently i have been trying to upload my android application onto Huawei gallery but on the review i got this

We have noticed that the App you submitted is a test version. For more information, please refer to the rule 3.6 of "AppGallery Review Guidelines": https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30202 ­[Suggestion]: Please upload the official version.

can anybody tell me the reason this is happening?

Comment: Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: Can you please specify how you're generating the apk?

Comment: @shirley this is the appid 102955265

Comment: @m0skit0 i already uploaded it to the the play store, i developed an new key and vertificate and uploaded them, then attached the new key to the app to upload to the huawei store

Comment: just realized that i put that it works for tablet but i haven't added any tablet layouts, could that be the reason?

Comment: @K.hamdan All right. The app description is that it is a test version. The reviewer cannot access the app. Therefore, the app was rejected.

Comment: where can i find that and also how can i change that

Comment: @K.hamdan Before you submit your apps for public release, make sure the apps comply with the requirements in [this document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30202).

Comment: @K.hamdan The correct compatible device types must be selected for your app. (phone, tablet, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is located as a test app, it may contain Test/ testing or beta/ data content. If it is not a test app, please note that the app is not a test app, and submit it again.